# Draggable div with no fixed size will leave the parent's container

Tags: css, reactjs, draggable

I have a somewhat custom-made Draggable component. The point of the component is to make an image draggable, but only inside the parent's container.

Parent's container has a fixed size, in this particular example it's 700 x 700 pixels. In the image component, the image itself is wrapped in a div. The problem is that the image will behave normally (won't leave the parent's container) if the div has specified width and height. But, if the width and height are set to fit-content, or not even set at all, the image will leave the parent's container.

Hypothetically speaking, let's say that image's size is 200 x 200 pixels. If height and width of div wrapping the image is not specified, the image will be able to leave the container, but will  stop once the top-left point of it is on the edge of the container.

To sum up the problem: If the div has not fixed width and height, the image can leave container until its top left point is inside of the container, meaning that the whole size of div / image is not taken into consideration.

The code of the draggable image:

```
  <Draggable bounds="parent" onDrag={(e, ui) => this.handleDrag(e, ui, imageID)}>
    <div className="divInlineBox">
      <img className="overlappingPNG" src={imagePath} width={imageWidth} height={imageHeight}/>
    </div>                  
  </Draggable>
```

CSS:

```
.divInlineBox {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: black;
}

.overlappingPNG {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Is it possible for my div to have flexible size and not leave the container?